# C++ declaration error

Tags: c++, arrays, function, declare

I am currently working with arrays and moving around the data from array to array, however, that isnt the issue the issue is within my void functions more specifically my for loops i dont know why it won't compile when it looks correct to me and I see in my teacher's note that it is possible to declare an integer in a for loop within a void function but still receiving errors.

Error:
exercise11.cpp:49:12: error: ânâ was not declared in this scope
   for(i=0; n=11; n

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int MAX = 20;

void reformat(double[], double[], int);
void sum(double[], double[], int);

int main()
{
  double input[MAX];
  double newarray[MAX];
  cout << fixed << right << setprecision(5);
  cout << "Morgan Kiger Lec#1002 Lab#1005 Exercise #11" << endl << endl;

  for (int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
      cin >> input[i];
    }

  reformat(input, newarray, MAX);
  sum(input, newarray, MAX);

  return 0;
}


void reformat(double input[], double newarray[], int MAX)
{ 
  for(int i=0; int n=10; n<MAX; i++, n++)
    {
      newarray[n] = input[i]*2;
    }

  for(i=0; n=11; n<MAX; i++, n++)
    {
      newarray[i] = pow(input[n], 0.3);
    }

  return;
}

void sum(double input[], double newarray[], int MAX)
{
  double sum1;
  double sum2;

  cout << "Input Array" << setw(5) << "2nd Array" << endl;

  for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
      sum1 = input[i] + sum1;
    }

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
      sum2 = newarray[i] + sum2;
    }

  for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
      cout << input[i] << setw(5) << newarray[i] << endl;
    }

  cout << "sum of input valves = " << sum1 << endl;
  cout << "sum of 1st 10 values in changed array = " << sum2 << endl;

 return;
}
```

Comment: Punctuation exists for a reason. The error message is telling you everything. There is no "n" declared in the scope of this for-loop; the previous "n" is limited to the for-loop in which it was declared.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is wrong, because only the first statement in a `for` preamble is the declaration part — you've attempted to use two statements for that job.

However, you *can* declare multiple variables in a single statement, which is what you presumably intended to do:

```
for (int i = 0, n = 10; n < NAX; i++, n++)
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now, these variables only exist for the duration of the loop. That is their "scope". For your next loop, you have to declare them again.

So, instead of this:

```
for(i=0; n=11; n<MAX; i++, n++)
```

repeat the above, substituting `11` for `10` in the new declaration (if that wasn't a typo).

Also, I believe you wrote `input[i]` when you meant `input[n]`. Otherwise `n` is pointless in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
void reformat(double input[], double newarray[], int MAX)
{ 
for(int i=0; int n=10; n<MAX; i++, n++)
  {
  newarray[n] = input[i]*2;
  }

for(i=0; n=11; n<MAX; i++, n++)
  {
  newarray[i] = pow(input[n], 0.3);
  }

  return;
}
```

When you declare a variable in a **for** block as you have done here with the variable **i** , it only exists for the duration of the following block.

The second **for** block above needs to declare a new loop variable, since the first i no longer exists, after its block has completed executing.

Answer (score 0):

You've got couple of problems with the use of variables in the `for` loops in `reformat`.

```
for(int i=0; int n=10; n<MAX; i++, n++)
```

is not right. A `for` loop cannot have four clauses. You need to use:

```
for(int i=0, n=10; n<MAX; i++, n++)
```

The second problem is that the above declaration makes `i` and `n` to be valid only in the `for` loop. Their scope ends in the `for` loop. They are not valid in the second `for` loop. They need to be redeclared in the second `for` loop.

```
for(int i=0, n=11; n<MAX; i++, n++)
```